# Error - Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I am getting the following error when trying to install GCC 11 compiler using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = '/usr/lib/python3.11'
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python311.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.11',
    '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f6170d70740 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

I am getting the same error when I run other commands: `lsb_release -a` , `/usr/bin/python3`.

I had uninstalled Python 3.11 just before reaching this error (I notice that python 3.11 is mentioned in the error message).

I have checked for other answers to this issue, and the suggestion is to unset PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME. However, they are not set, as the error message shows.

Could anyone suggest how I could resolve this ?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: No, I still have the issue

Comment: Have you figured it out?